# Maintaining html control state in php?

Tags: php, html, postback

When a user fails to register, the fields disappear cause there is a postback to the server..

So for example, I have this:

```
<input name="email" type="text"  id="email1"/>
```

If the user fails to login, what will happen is that the fields will disappear. I could do this.

```
<input name="email" type="text"  id="email1" value="<?php echo isset($_post["email"])?$_post["email"]:""; ?>"/>
```

But it is a bit a long way, is there an easier way to maintain a state?

Comment: Not really, because your script will provide a blank form and the browser will display it. However if you use a form library, they normally come with such functionality. So that *might* be easier for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make one helper to manipulate HTML form tags. There are many libraries that you can find in web, or just made one.

Most MVC frameworks have features like this (Cakephp,codeigniter), but theres standalones too.

Samples/Doc:

codeigniter:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

cakephp:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper

akelos:
http://akelos.org/wiki/forms